# Realtime checking the progress monitor using Job.getJobManager.IsIdle()

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to continuously check if the progress monitor has an operation that is running in the background.

For this, I used `Job.getJobManager.IsIdle()`.

I have tried the following:

1. Put it inside a Job.

```java
    WorkspaceJob job = new WorkspaceJob("Hello") 
    {
        @Override
        public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
        {
            while(!Job.getJobManager().isIdle())
            {
                System.out.println(!Job.getJobManager().isIdle());
            }
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.setPriority(Job.SHORT);
    job.schedule();
```

But this does not work as `Job.getJobManager.isIdle` will never return false because `Job 'Hello'` is running.

2. Put it inside an asynchronous thread.

   ```java
   new Thread(new Runnable()
       {
           @Override
           public void run()
           {
               Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
               {
                   @Override
                   public void run()
                   {
                       while(!Job.getJobManager().isIdle())
                       {
                           System.out.println("hi");
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
       }).start();
   ```

But this does not work either as this will freeze the main Eclipse GUI preventing other processes (if there are any existing) to finish.

If anyone has suggestions or any input on how it should be done, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a job change listener `IJobChangeListener` to listen for all changes to job states. You can than test for idle in appropriate places in the listener. Do **not** try and loop calling `isIdle`.

You can use the `JobChangeAdapter` class which provides default implementations of the `IJobChangeListener` methods so that you only have to override the events you are interested in, probably just the `done` method:

```java
Job.getJobManager().addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void done(IJobChangeEvent event)
    {
      if (Job.getJobManager().isIdle() {
        // Manager is idle
      }
    }
  });
```